# performance of symbolicc++

Tags: c++

Anyone has experience with the SymbolicC++ ? I'm trying to solve some linear problem with this library, but the performance seems not acceptable, here's my test

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4800 4801 4101 4390)
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "Symbolic/symbolicc++.h"

int main() {
    // x==10  y==9  z==7
    Symbolic x("x"), y("y"), z("z");
    Equations rules = (
        x + y + z == 26,
        x - y == 1,
        2*x - y + z == 18
    );

    list<Symbolic> s = (x, y, z);

    list<Equations> result = solve(rules, s); // slow here

    for(auto& x : result) {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
}
```

The **solve** function takes 402ms(debug)/67ms(release) on an i7 cpu, is that too slow for a simple problem like this?
Anyone knows why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbolic computations are slow, they need if you want to handle formulaes.

If you just want to solve system of linear equations, consider using tool, specially created for that, like Eigen(http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), BLAS(http://www.netlib.org/blas/).

Also read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kassak, just got this done with Eigen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Eigen/Dense"
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    Matrix3f A;
    Vector3f b;
    A <<    1, 1, 1, 
            1,-1, 0, 
            2,-1, 1;
    b <<    26, 1,18;
    cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
    cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
    Vector3f x = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
    cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
}
```

Comment: more info on this method. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/systems-linear-equations-matrices.html